# CSS: Horizontal UL: Getting it centered

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, center

I'm trying to make a horizontal  menu/list.  It has a mix of independent buttons and buttons that are wrapped in their own individual forms.

With much hacking I got all of the buttons, in forms and not in forms to align horizontally.

I haven't been able to get the whole thing to center on the page though.

Could someone point out to me what I am not seeing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost:7001/nsd/images/favicon.ico">
    <style type = "text/css">
        #horizontal_li_menu
        {
            margin:0 auto;
            text-align:center;
            border: 1px solid green;
            width:750px;
            list-style-type: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding:0 auto;
        }

        #horizontal_li_menu li 
        { 
            display: inline;
            float:left;
            padding-right: 10px;

         }

    </style>

</head>

    <body>







<ul id = "horizontal_li_menu">
    <li>
        <input value="Update" onclick="location.href='#'" name="button" type="button"/>
    </li>

    <li>
        <form name="formExportVECI" method="post" action="exportveci">
            <input name="person_id" value="661774" type="hidden">
            <input name="submitExport" value="Export To Microsoft Excel" type="submit">
        </form>

    </li>  
    <li>
        <form id="ufdh" name="formImportVECI" action="importveci" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input name="person_id" value="661774" type="hidden">
                <input value="Import From Microsoft Excel" path="Upload" type="submit">
                <input id="fileData" name="fileData" value="" type="file">
        </form>
    </li>

    <li>
        <input value="Search/Home" onclick="location.href='search'" name="buttonHome" type="button"/>
    </li>
    </ul>






</body></html>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not seeing the challenge, but that could be because I can't see your 'veci_files/nsd.css' stylesheet.

Comment: New to CSS.

I edited the quoted code in light of the comments I got.  The suggestions did not work, but I managed to center the menu by reducing the width of the menu.  If someone can suggest a smarter and more robust way of doing it I will give them the points.  If not I will give the points to the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to your CSS:

`#horizontal_li_menu_container ul` and `horizontal_li_menu_container_ul` are selecting the same element. I'm not sure if you realize this.

Also, when using floats, you need to **clear them**.

Answer (score 0):

#### To center a block element *horizontally* within a page, or another element

Use

```
 
   #element_id{margin: 0 auto;}
```

That will center the element around its container.

#### So, to center the list *horizontally* on the page

apply the above style to the **ul**, and not to the **li**. 
**BTW,** unless the div with id **horizontal_li_menu_container** has additional content, it is redundant; the **ul** will work perfectly without it. 
 If that doesn't work, check the following:

1. Find the sum of the **widths, paddings, and margins** of all the **li**s in that **ul**
2. Make sure the sum equals the width of the **ul**
3. Make sure the container div has no specified width, or it has already been centered on the page

If all those are true, the above style will work.

 
Hope this helps.