# How to horizontally align center <ul> used as menu which is floated left?

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls2y8v97/3/)

I can not horizontal align center `<ul>` menu, which is floated left. I can use margin-left and give a hard coded value sych as 200px or so (same problem occurs when say, margin-left: 40% and margin-right:40%, this time margins try to protect their width thus they drop the ul to the down when pahe width is small enough), then it is ok, but I want it automatically align to center even when resize (responsive).
[CSS: Horizontal UL: Getting it centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849446/css-horizontal-ul-getting-it-centered) is not a solution, because my menu **should float left**, it is not alone in the menu bar. 
I hope it is clear

Comment: What is not clear is what you mean by horizontal-align... I mean, where should it go? Can you explain the needed expected result?

Comment: You should be using `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ocurrs in float elements. Try this:

```
#top-bar p {
  /* Try */
  position: absolute;
}

#top-bar ul {
  float: left; /* Delete this one */
  horizontal-align: center; /* Delete this one */
  position: relative;
  width: 50%; /* Adjust at your need */
}

#top-bar li {
 float: left; /* Delete */
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By this statement:

> my menu should float left, it is not alone in the menu bar

I believe your mistake is actually your false premise. You don't need to float the elements to keep them inline. If your point is keeping the `p` and the `ul` side-by-side, change their `display` property.

Floating will remove the ability of centering the elements, but `display: inline-block` for example, lets you horizontally align the elements by their parent, with `text-align: center`:

[**See updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls2y8v97/5/)

```
    #top-bar{
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 35px;
        background-color: #D3D3D3;
        font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #top-bar p{
        margin:0;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-left:10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #top-bar ul{
        margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
        horizontal-align: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Comment: i am surprised by the number of questions i see that say "i floated my element left, but now i can't center it!".

Comment: This was what I want, still float left at p, but display-inline for ul  http://jsfiddle.net/ertugrulmurat/Ls2y8v97/